# How to enable/disable SIM cards in a system level application?

Tags: android, android-source

I'm developing a system application for my custom android OS. I want to disable/enable SIM cards from application and do not want user to open settings. How can disable enable sim cards in aosp application?

I have tried `setSimPowerStateForSlot` method  from `TelephonyManager`
but it does power of the SIM slots and I could not get any information about SIM card if slote is powered off.

Comment: Hey, @Muhammad Nadeem how did you manage to do that? please share code. Thanks

Comment: I just used setSimPowerStateForSlot from  TelephonyManager

Comment: i'm using the same code but it's not working. Can you please tell what u did more?

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelShoukat please check if your app has appropriate permissions granted

Comment: I'm doing this work on system default app `Messaging`.

Comment: android.Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE, please make sure this permission is is in whitelisted permission list.

Comment: if you need any further help, please contact me through email. nadeemgujjar71@gmail.com

Comment: Check Email i've sent an email